# Convert string type to FileUpload type

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

```
        public class SavePhotoDatabase
        {
            public static byte[] SavePhoto(FileUpload fileup)
            {
            .
            .
            }
        }
```

And I have `string file="PhotoUpload";`

Now I would like to give `file` as parameter to `SavePhoto(FileUpload fileup)`.

How can I do this ?

How can I use `string` as `FileUpload` ?

Comment: Is "PhotoUpload" a filename to the actual file?

Comment: @Yorro , "PhotoUpload" will be 'id' of FileUpload.
  `<asp:FileUpload ID="PhotoUpload" CssClass="btn-block" runat="server" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure exactly what you're asking for, but I believe you want to pass the id of the `<asp:FileUpload>` control into the static function.

If that is correct, I believe you want something along the lines of...

```
public static byte[] SavePhoto(string fileUploadId)
{
  System.Web.UI.Page page = (System.Web.UI.Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
  if (page != null)
  {
    FileUpload uploadCtrl = (FileUpload)page.FindControl(fileUploadId);
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Good idea but I use also master page. Can you improve this answer for master page ?

Comment: Would it not be better to just find the control on the page that you're looking for it, and pass the control into a function?  Why does it need to find it as part of the function?

Comment: it is also possible, I tried but I can't.
I accept this string from Ajax Post method.
And in the my server side [WebMethod] I can't find control using its "id".

Comment: Sorry, but you're adding far too many things into this question... Master Pages, AJAX calls... how the hell am I supposed to know what you're trying to do??  I gave you the answer to your original question

Comment: Yeah I know, I accept this answer for my original question.

Comment: Thank you for the accepted mark.  I would suggest you start a new question, detailing EVERYTHING that you require.  There is no point asking a small question and expecting people to know that there is a lot, lot more to it!  Good luck